# Download & Upload file using plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, form-data

I am trying to get an image from an url and post it to a server, but I receive a 400 error code during upload.

The code is this:

```
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("get", e.srcUrl, true);

                xhr.onload = function () { 
                let fd = new FormData();
                fd.append("file", xhr.response);

                var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr2.open("post", hostname + "/API/PushManaging?handler=FileImage&type=image", true);
                xhr2.send(fd);
            }
            xhr.send();
```

The URL hostname + "/API/PushManaging?handler=FileImage&type=image" works correctly using a classic form and selecting the file from a classic input type=file element.

How can I resolve this?
Thanks

EDIT:
I don't know if this is useful or not, but the Server where the file should upload is based on .NET Core: the url is a Razor Page. I am debugging the server with a breakpoint but it's never called, so the problem is client side I think

[image]

Comment: Where do you get error while downloading or uploading ?

Comment: Uploading. I will edit the post to specify this, sorrry

Comment: You may need to convert the response to a blob before sending it off to the PushManaging request. I'm not sure what your browser requirements are, but just google around for converting response to blob, there are many different ways.

Comment: It's a Chrome Extension, so.. Chrome is ok! Can you give me some example code? Thank you

Comment: 400 means bad request, always client-side. Do you also need to pass username and password for this server ?

Comment: No, there is no auth needs for the server.

Comment: @rootkonda "always client-side"? Sounds like someone who works on the server side speaking... :) There are many reasons for a 400 error. It is definitely a mismatch between what the server is expecting and what the client is sending, however.

Comment: what do you get in xhr.response ?? check this link on how to send files using formdata objects - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects